# Execute a function after a test for character length

Tags: jquery, character-limit

I'm trying to truncate the amount of text in a div when the text reaches 40 characters in length and add an ellipsis after the truncation. This is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".trim").text(function(index, text) {
return text.substr(0, 40)+' ...';
});
});
```

The problem is it adds the ellipsis even if the character length is less than 40 characters, adding an ellipsis even when the text is no truncated. So next I tried a conditional to run the function only if the character length is less than 40 characters, to no avail:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
if($(".trim").length > 40) {
$(".trim").text(function(index, text) {
return text.substr(0, 40)+' ...';
});
}
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there! Your condition is not checking against the length of the text in the div. You are checking the `.length` of the jQuery object, which would be equal to `1` (number of elements found by the selector). You need to check against the length of the actual text *inside* the `div`. Get rid of the `if` outside and move the length-check inside the function that you pass into `.text()`:

```
$(".trim").text(function(index, text) {
    var newText = text;

    if(text.length > 40) {
        newText = text.substr(0, 40) + "...";
    }

    return newText;
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, Vivin. Now a great little script.

Comment: Actually, Vivin, what I'm trying to truncate is a sentence that contains a link. When I use this script, it does truncate the sentence, but it also breaks the link. Any ideas on how to avoid this? Am I correct that it's counting the characters in the html and not the "outputted" text?

Comment: Could you post that again using backticks? Raw HTML is ignored so I cannot see what it is that you are trying to truncate.

Comment: This is the the line of html/php I'm trying to truncate:
`<span><strong>Course: </strong><?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'courses', '', ', ', '' ); ?></span>`
The php function is a Wordpress function that outputs the name of a "course". Sometimes the "course" text (the name of a course) is too long, so I want to keep it to 40 characters. This Wordpress php function returns the "course" as a link, which is what I need. The script is truncating the "course," but is stripping away the link.

Comment: That's because it's giving you the text inside the `.trim` element. You probably want to change the selector to `$(".trim span")` so that you end up working with the actual `span` elements.

Comment: sorry -- i actually changed the html `<span>` to `<span class="trim">` so the script is only targeting inside the <span>. Seems like that Wordpress php function is breaking somehow.

Comment: AH EASY - I just add another selector `$(".trim a")` to work with just the link elements and problem solved. Thanks, Vivin.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out! :)